# How do I avoid this catastrophic regex backtracking issue?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse the follow page.

```
url="https://learnjapanesedaily.com/most-common-japanese-words.html/6/#1000-most-common-japanese-words-week-6";
```

Code:

```
private void Getwords(string html)
{
    int new1 = 0;
    Regex r1 = new Regex(@"<p>\d{1,3}.\s(.*?)\s:\s(.*?)<\/p>", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    MatchCollection matches = r1.Matches(html);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
        if (!wdic.ContainsKey(groups[1].Value))
        {
            wdic.Add(groups[1].Value, groups[2].Value);
            new1++;
            listBox1.Items.Add(groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("New words added = " + new1.ToString());
}
```

When I run it, I'll get 61 matches instead of 60 matches because the last match will match a really long line. I only want it to check and parse 1~3 lines at most. Is it possible?

Comment: Do. Not. Even. Try. To. Parse. Html. With. Regex. Use the proper tool for the job.

Comment: I know, I was learning regex so I used this as an example to find out how to do it with regex this time as a practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.*?` could also match " : " and newlines, and so if (in theory) you would get a string with many such occurrences (like " : : : : : : : : : : "), or it could even match `</p>` across a long multiline input, trying to match something without success, and so there could be a lot of backtracking happening.

The solution to be more precise in what that the first `.*?` should match: you could for instance require that it wouldn't match a colon, nor a line break.

Not the problem, but you seem to want to match a *literal* dot after the initial number, and then you should precede it with a backslash.

Here is a correction:

```
@"<p>\d{1,3}\.\s([^\n\r:]*?)\s:\s([^\n\r]*?)<\/p>"
```

On a more general note: it is a bad idea to parse HTML with regex. Parse the HTML using an HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to learn how it worked, so I used this example.